# Colored Data in 1 String in a gridview in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I have a resultgridview from a search query.

In this gridview I have a text e.g. **"This is a nice Car for you"**

If the user search for the word **"Car"** I like to show the word **"Car"** in the string in the gridview in red and bold.

How to do it?

Comment: Where/how would the user "search"? Or more general: how is the user interaction meant to work?

Comment: Its a Request.Querystring in the PageLoad Method.

Comment: ??? I do not understand. Do you mean the user enters the string to search into the querystring by hand? Or how does the searchstring get into the querystring?

Comment: What I am not sure, is do you won to search for the word, after the first search, using javascript ? or using the first search keywords ? and do you won to search for one word ? or more.

Comment: @Aristos: thanks for getting rid of the horrible "aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbccccccccccc" stuff :)

Comment: Don't flame my AAAAAABBBBBBCCC Stuff o.o =(((( Makes me sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define a css-class f.e.:

```
.searchmatch
{
   color: red;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

... and in [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) you could split the name into the parts that match and the parts that do not match. In the TemplateField of the Gridview-Column with the name you could f.e. add a Div(runat="server"). In RowDataBound you can find it with its id, its from Type [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28VS.71%29.aspx). Then you can use the InnerHtml property to assign the match part's span its searchmatch-css-class.

**UPDATE**: I think this could be helpful in GridView too: [Highlighting Search Keywords in a DataGrid Web Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121522/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072402-1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As I still do not really understand what you are trying to achieve this is just an (not so) educated guess :)

Maybe you could use the [GridView.RowCreated Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated%28VS.80%29.aspx) event to set a CSS loaded `<span class="...">` tag around the search text (that comes from a text box or whatever)?

**EDIT**

RowDataBound (as suggested by others) would probably be the better event to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i <= 32; i++)
            {
                if (gr.Cells[i].Text like '%"car"%'")
                {
                   gr.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("White");
                   gr.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("#275F8F");
                }
                else if (gr.Cells[i].Text == "L")
                {
                    gr.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("White");
                    gr.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Red");
                }
                else if (gr.Cells[i].Text == "P")
                {
                    gr.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Black");

                }
            }
        }
```